# How to check each StringVar separately via trace in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote some code to create GUI for user creator:

```
class Account(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, controller, entry_names, *args, **kwargs):
         tk.Frame.__init__(self, controller)
         self.grid(row=0, column=0)

         self.data_entry_name = entry_names
         self.entry_list = {}

    for line, entry in enumerate(self.data_entry_name):
        lbl_tmp = tk.Label(self, text=entry)
        lbl_tmp.grid(row=line, column=0)
        ent_tmp = tk.Entry(self, width=20)
        ent_tmp.grid(row=line, column=1)
        self.entry_list[entry] = ent_tmp
        if entry == self.data_entry_name[-1]:
            self.btn_send = tk.Button(self, text="Create", command=lambda: self.check_and_create(controller))
            self.btn_send.grid(row=line + 1, column=1)
            self.btn_back = tk.Button(self, text="Back", command=lambda: controller.lift(controller.choice_frame))
            self.btn_back.grid(row=line + 1, column=0)

            ...

class User(Account):
   def __init__(self, controller, *args, **kwargs):
       self.data_entry_name = ["First name: ", "Last name: ", "Address: ", "Zip code: ", "City: ", "Password: ",
                            "PIN: ", "Money: "]
       Account.__init__(self, controller, self.data_entry_name, *args, **kwargs)

       self.pin_value = tk.StringVar()
       self.pin_value.trace_add('write', lambda *_, var=self.pin_value: self.check_entry(var))
       self.entry_list["PIN: "].configure(textvariable=self.pin_value, show="*")
       self.entry_list["Password: "].configure(show="*")
       self.money_value = tk.StringVar()
       self.money_value.trace_add('write', lambda *_, var=self.money_value: self.check_entry(var))
       self.entry_list["Money: "].configure(textvariable=self.money_value)

   def check_entry(self, var):
       if var == self.pin_value:
           lens = len(self.pin_value.get())
           if lens > 4:
               self.pin_value.set(self.pin_value.get()[0:4])
           try:
               i = int(self.pin_value.get())
           except ValueError:
               messagebox.showerror("Data error!", "Use only integers for PIN number!")
               self.pin_value.set(self.pin_value.get()[0:lens-1])
       elif var == self.money_value:
           lens = len(self.money_value.get())
           try:
               i = int(self.money_value.get())
           except ValueError:
               messagebox.showerror("Data error!", "Use only numbers for Money!")
               self.pin_value.set(self.pin_value.get()[0:lens-1])
```

check_entry method should check given tk.StringVar() and It works in both cases. When I entry letter to PIN field or 5th digit it works as I want, it shows me only one messagebox with information about wrong data in PIN field. When I type letter to the Money field, method also works fine, but after that program automatically execute part of code responsible for PIN check and I get two messageboxes, one for Money, and one for PIN. Is there any way to check this variables separately? I read tkinter documentation but there is not much information. I think It might be problem with trace function, but I not really understand how it works.

Comment: create two separated functions instead of one `check_entry` and you will have no problem.

Comment: first you could use `print()` in `check_entry` to check what you have in `var` and if it is `self.pin_value` or `self.money_value` - maybe it will help you to find problem. OR learn how to use debuger.

Comment: check_entry was splited into two methods before. And when I used trace without lambda var argument was 'PY_VAR0' for PIN and for money 'PY_VAR1'. When I used lambda in that case, print() shows correct variable object.

Comment: Frankly, If I would have two separated functions for `StringVars` then I would use `self.pin_value` and `self.money_value` directly in these functions, without sending them as arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `check_entry` when you check `money` then you use `self.pin_value.set()` in `except` so it automatically runs `check_entry` for PIN. You should use `self.money_value.set()` in `except`

Comment: Ahhhh, I copied code from PIN section and forget to change variable hah. Now it works fine :) sorry for problem and thanks for your time.